# Testing in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I have `Dashboard` component like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataTable from './DataTable';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return <DataTable />;
  }
}

export default connect()(Dashboard);
```

My test is like below

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});


describe('Addition', () => {
  it('knows that 2 and 2 make 4', () => {
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

I am trying to run test using this command `npm test App.test.js`.

I am getting below error

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Dashboard)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Dashboard) in connect options.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dashboard` is connected to redux, which requires a store. You have a two possibilities :

- use [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) and [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store) in order to configure  a store used when you're mounting your component. This is not well maintainable and leads to a strong dependency between Component and store.
- export the non-connected Dashboard (in addition to the default export connected), and mount (eventually with the required props). This is much simpler and maintainable.

```js
export class Dashboard extends Component {
   render() {
     return <DataTable />;
   }
}


// Test :

import { Dashboard } from './components/Dashboard';

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, div);
```

*Note*: I think you simplified your `connect()` for the example purpose, because it does not do anything here, but if this is your real implementation you could drop the connect part and still use the default export for your test.

Comment: Thanks @colinux for your reply. I have `connect()` in `<DataTable />` component also. As per your reply `ReactDOM` is unable handle this situation, I have to use `Enzyme` instead of  `ReactDOM`, right ?

Comment: @abuabu you can also test Datatable the same way , and just ensuring Dashboard renders a Datatable component. There is also react-testing-library which becomes popular theses days, which test from an user perspective https://testing-library.com/

Comment: Thanks @colinux. As per your reply `ReactDOM` is unable handle this situation, I have to use `Enzyme` instead of `ReactDOM`, right ?